# Media Queries for SASS Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, gruntjs

Current Bootstrap Version `3.3.7`

Are all media queries for bootstrap-sass deprecated, I tried running one media query and kept getting errors below.

How can I use media queries in bootstrap-sass?

[See Image Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6CMm.png)

[See Error Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQTBd.png)
My style.scss file

```
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
.navbar{
    height: $navbar-height * 2;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots. ;)

Comment: You need to post your `style.scss` file but It looks like you have a variable set to `@screen-lg-min`

Comment: @FredBarclay, I have included my style.scss, media query example. The screenshot was to show the page from the variables file as it is.

Comment: @Barryman9000, I have added a media query I tried creating using the examples shown below. if I run `grunt` the error shows up.

Comment: @Anthony Cano - right, you shouldn't use that `@` symbol. I should have been clearer in my above comment, you can't use the `@` symbol for variables in sass, it should be `$screen-lg-min`

Answer (score 4):

Variables in SASS are marked with a `$` sign, not `@`. So the line should look like this:

```
@media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
    .navbar{
        height: $navbar-height * 2;
    }
}
```